# What kind of spider is this (from Bangladesh)?

Tags: species-identification, zoology

I just saw this spider in my bathroom. I was wondering what kind of spider is this and if it is venomous.

Country: Bangladesh

[image: Spider]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only three Sparassidae (huntsman spider) species [have been observed](https://www.inaturalist.org/observations?place_id=7154&taxon_id=47867&view=species) in Bangladesh on iNaturalist. Only one looks anything like the individual in your photo: [Heteropoda venatoria](https://www.inaturalist.org/observations?locale=en-US&place_id=7154&taxon_id=48765). I venture it's a male based on the dark brown patterns on its prosoma and the overall body's lighter brown color. Most spiders are venomous, but according to a University of Florida IFAS publication, [this spider isn't dangerous](https://edis.ifas.ufl.edu/publication/in317) to humans. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

This is a **huntsman spider** , which is venomous but it's affect on humans is not so reactive , it's not can cause several symptom like itching, swelling,in more severe vomitting and nausea like ,
It was a coincidence to identify it because my cockroach also have the same upper structure like it so. I thought it should have some relation and the results were **these are cockroach eating ** I didn't know the exact reason behind this unique relation